# Distribution lists in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, configuration

I'm looking to move all of our Exchange Public Folder contents to a WSS 3.0 server including several contact lists.  The problem I've run into is that the distribution lists that have been created in the public folders are apparently not supported in the Sharepoint contact lists.  Does anyone have a work around for this or know how we can create useable DL's that will still sync into the Outlook client?

Answer (score 1):

I work on SharePoint and am the PM responsible for Exchange integration in the next release.

Check out the directory management service ([link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263260.aspx)). DMS allows you to have SharePoint Groups where the membership is pushed into distribution lists. While it doesn't allow you to associate existing DLs with groups, it might help you out.

note: you will need to have the recipient update service (Exchange stuff) running on your network to make use of DMS.

Comment: All of the contact entries that I'm working with are external to our organization (no part of AD) - does this still work for those?