# Moving distribution lists in Public Folders to Sharepoint Contacts?

Tags: sharepoint, exchange, migration

Now I know that if I connect to contact list in Sharepoint and drag and drop everything from the Exchange Public Folder contact list to the Sharepoint Contact list (connected through Outlook) it will transfer everything in the contact list to the sharepoint contact list.

What about distribution lists? Has anyone had a workaround for this? If a contact list is full of distribution lists the Contacts won't migrate over and the Sync Issues -> Local Failures folder is populated with all the distribution lists that couldn't be migrated.

Is there a way to migrate distribution lists? Any ideas how to set up the sharepoint contact list like a public folder contact list of distrubition lists? How would that contact list look on sharepoint? Should I just leave the contact lists that have distribution lists on public folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/15051/distribution-lists-in-sharepoint) previously on serverfault. Perhaps DMS could be your solution.

Comment: well even though that is really neat, and useful in the future I'm looking to migrate the distribution lists I already have into Sharepoint. Is that not possible?